# Node.js - find object in array by value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to get an object in an array by the value of one of its keys.

The array:

```
{
"privileges" : 
    [
      {
        "resource" : "login" ,
        "actions": ["true"]
      },
      {
        "resource":  "user" ,
        "actions": ["create","read"]
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is the expected result please?

Comment: I put console.log(user.role.privileges) and i got this privileges: [ { '0': [Object], '1': [Object], actions: [] } ] }

Comment: @HaythemHedfi Your accepted answer doesn't contain anything related to MongoDB, they why those tags?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let obj  = {
"privileges" : 
    [
      {
        "resource" : "login" ,
        "actions": ["true"]
      },
      {
        "resource":  "user" ,
        "actions": ["create","read"]
      }
    ]
}

function filterValue(value) {
return obj["privileges"].filter((object) => {
 return object["resource"] == value
})
}
console.log(filterValue("user"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use find method:

```
const a = {
    "privileges": [
      {
        "resource" : "login" ,
        "actions": ["true"]
      },
      {
        "resource":  "user" ,
        "actions": ["create","read"]
      }
    ]
};

var objFound = a.privileges.find(obj => obj.resource === "user");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are asking, but searching for the object property value would be with Ramda like this:

```
const a = {
    "privileges": [
      {
        "resource" : "login" ,
        "actions": ["true"]
      },
      {
        "resource":  "user" ,
        "actions": ["create","read"]
      }
    ]
}

R.find(R.propEq("resource", "login"), a.privileges);
```